# .htaccess redirect a broken link domain.com/.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i need to redirect the broken url like

domain.com/.php to domain.com/index.php

anyone know how??i try to use some htaccess generator like

http://htaccessredirect.net/index.php

and get this code but redirect loop/error

i have tried the following code,but not work

```
Redirect 301 /.php index.php
```

and also i tried, but error

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^/.php$
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that you've got a rule that adds that .php to the  end?

Comment: no, both is full code inside .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the period or it becomes part of the regular expression.

Like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/\.php$ /index.php [L,R=301]
```

or:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/\.php index.php
```

Comment: Which one did you use? And: I don't recall apache giving an "object not found" error, that sounds more like php. Or do you mean a 404 ?

Comment: i tried both,

erm...should be 404, because that file is not exists for sure, im using some framework, it got bug that sometime will redirect to /.php, need time to find out, need temporary use .htaccess first

domain.com/.php <<<